# How to program a POS Printer using USB on Visual Basic 6

Tags: printing, vb6, usb, point-of-sale

How to program a POS Printer using USB on Visual Basic 6

Answer (score 1):

To access the printer settings, you can use the API function DocumentProperties. Here's the declaration for VB6:

```
Public Declare Function DocumentProperties Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "DocumentPropertiesA"_
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal pDeviceName As String, _
  ByRef pDevModeOutput As DEVMODE, ByRef pDevModeInput As DEVMODE, _
  ByVal fMode As Long) As Long
```

Here are some details: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167345

You can use the other API printing functions to print to any windows printer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162861(VS.85).aspx